# ASP.NET push notification using Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

I have asp.net page where some file manipulation is performed. So when user click on that page a browser show hourglass and waiting for response. I would like to know is it possible to send response to user two times in one request cycle, before time-expense action and after? I can't change action workflow for that page and can't use ajax or other push methods except Response object.

Comment: I suggest reading **comet programming** and **server-sent events**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first suggest reading **[server-sent events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/)** and [**comet programming**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). But to keep an HTTP connection alive, I think you can send **keep-alive** header in first response, then don't close the response and wait till you send the second chunk.